# KeyError: 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to set values of column named 'barony2' in data frame 'df', if it's 'add_suburb' column contains ref_file's current iterrows' 'Townland' value using the following code.

```
df = pd.read_csv('a.csv')
ref_file = pd.read_csv('b.csv')

for index, row in ref_file.iterrows():
    cond = str(row['Townland']) in df.add_suburb
    df.loc[cond, 'barony2'] = str(row['Barony'])
```

I get `KeyError: 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'` Any help is highly appreciated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/saiki/PycharmProjects/webcrawl/edit_address2.py", line 46, in <module>
    import_encounters2()
  File "C:/Users/saiki/PycharmProjects/webcrawl/edit_address2.py", line 20, in import_encounters2
    df.loc[cond, 'barony2'] = str(row['Barony'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 132, in __setitem__
    self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 263, in _setitem_with_indexer
    key, _ = convert_missing_indexer(idx)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1824, in convert_missing_indexer
    raise KeyError("cannot use a single bool to index into setitem")
KeyError: 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'
```

Comment: `cond` is True or False, set using the `in` statement.  What do you expect it to be?

Comment: yes, but I am wondering why  df.loc[cond, 'barony2'] = str(row['Barony']) not workin cdarke

Comment: It isn't clear which line is giving you the error.  Please post the exact error and traceback as part of the question.

Comment: i am sorry cdarke, updated now

Comment: cond = str(row['Townland']) in df.add_suburb is always false even though the value is in df.add_suburb

Comment: I changed to cond = df['add_suburb'].str.contains(str(row['Townland'])), now it works :)